# Need to bring the data home/On-Prem from vendor's Kafka Topic

Tags: apache-kafka

The vendor publishes frequent Async responses to Kafka Topic which resides in the vendor DC.
We need to get that info into our company.
What we don't want to do is:

- to write a (polling) Kafka consumer service to read off their Kafka Topic

We want them to call our Rest API (callback url) to publish the information.

Are there any options to configure a trigger on (their) Kafka topic to call a (external) REST API as and when a message is written into the topic?

We would like them to call our API so we can route it thru our API Gateway and handle all the crosscutting concerns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want **them** to call your service, or have them write a secondary event to anywhere, then you need to ask **them** to do that... No real alternatives there.

If you have access to their Kafka service, I see no reason why embedding a consumer into your API would be an issue.

Or you could use MirrorMaker/Replicator to copy their Kafka to your own local Kafka, but you still need some consumer to get data over to a REST action.